# QGIS Raster map, smoothing pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, smoothing

I am trying to generate a map in Qgis which makes it possible to see the temperature of a region during a heatwave. This was a great succes. However, I want to add shades as well, since shades lower the temperature.

Now I have the following map:

[image]
.

On this map we see a part of a city, with red being warmer and blue beging colder. Tree shades for instance make some parts of a street cooler. As you can see some area's have become very pixel-ish. I would like to smooth this map a bit so that for instance one orange pixel within a group of blue pixels, takes over the value of its neighbour and turn into blue as well.

Does anybody has an idea for this?

Comment: have you checked bi-linear, nearest neighbor, modal or cubic re-sampling? r.resamp.interp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some googling I found the SAGA Gaussian Filter in the qgis toolbox. After filtering the raster, a much smoother raster came out.

Comment: Where have you found the Gaussian Filter in SAGA?

Comment: @PhilippB. When you open SAGA you can find in the Tool Libraries: Grid -> Filter -> Gaussian Filter.