# Contour Polygon Alternatives on QGIS

Tags: qgis, vectorization, smoothing

I am trying various ways to make polygons from raster data using 1 m DEMs. I am using QGIS 3.16 Hannover I have tried vectorizing my data, which does work OK, but I would like smoother boundary lines that you get with contouring.

I have experimented with three techniques, all of which have their pros and cons. Ideally, the Contour Polygon would be the tool to use, however, it takes a very long time to process...too long (a few hours or my computer crashes for areas around 1000 ha in size). Alternatively I tried contouring with polylines, then converting to polygons. This takes  less time but I am having issues with unclosed polylines not creating polygons properly. My data set is so large that I can't be tracing this unclosed features to make polygons manually.

Are there anyway to make polygons from a raster file which is faster than the Contour Polygon tool? This tool would be my go to if it didn't take too long. Alternatively, if I could find a way to close my polylines then I can just convert to polygons which hopefully would take less time than using the contour polygon tool.

Comment: What are your QGIS and GDAL versions? How long time is too long? What intervals do you use for polygons, and could you provide some test data?

Comment: I updated my original post and addressed your comments. For this exercise, I have just been making a boolian raster and contouring with interval of 1. I can provide test data shortly.

Comment: You can find the data here. The data I am trying to work with are the raster files. I included my Depth to Water Index and also the boolian raster of the values I want to polygonize. In this case, I am trying to make polygons out of DTW values of 0 - 0.5.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u9l3h9kd6i9osyo/AAB4btlJPs7VM3J1IyKnhjkia?dl=0

Comment: I think the generally preferred way to get smooth contours is by smoothing the raster DEM first and then creating the contours.  You can search on that; here's just one stack exchange item I found: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265854/qgis-raster-map-smoothing-pixels.

Comment: Sorry, the link requires Dropbox account.